# How can I assign a variable from a static property using Expression Trees?

Tags: c#-4.0, expression-trees

Given a `ParameterExpression` of type `DateTime`, how do I generate an expression tree to assign `DateTime.Now.Date` to this variable?

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DateTime), "now");
var dateTimeNow = ... ? // What goes on this line?
var assignment = Expression.Assign(x, dateTimeNow);
```

I want the result of the assignment to be the value of `DateTime.Now.Date` when the resultant expression is invoked, not at compile-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var dateTimeNow = Expression.Property(
    Expression.Property(null, typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Now")),
    "Date");
```